# LessCss generate css from parent class until nested caller

Tags: css, less

Lets start by giving an example,

Say for instance I have the class:

```
 <html class="browser-ie"> ...
```

then on some element, I would like to call my mixin:

```
.browser-ie(@mixin){
        html.browser-ie {
                 @mixin();
        }
}
```

and be able to call it from for instance an element :

```
.main {
         .nested {
              .morenested {
                     .browser-ie({ min-height:100% });
              }
         }
}
```

and have it generate the following css:

```
html.browser-ie .main .nested .morenested { min-height:100%; }
```

**Is there anything in the toolbox that would allow for such a thing?**

Comment: The Sass tag was deliberately removed.  Do not ask about multiple unrelated languages in the same question (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272888/do-i-make-separate-questions-for-separate-programming-languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) in your precompiler. This should output your desired CSS.

```
.main {
  .nested {
    .morenested {
      html.browser-ie & {
        min-height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the parent selector can fall anywhere in a declaration, and it will inherit all of the classes you have nested into up to that point, and append them to your string.

Comment: I actually beat you too it by 1 second :P Good job. Thanks man! I have to wait 7 more minutes

Comment: However, I must say I am a bit dissapointed it doesn't work with mixins. I can't pass the code block to the mixin.

Comment: This doesn't work, but is there something that might? http://hastebin.com/ucivisinan.avrasm

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "keep in mind". Isn't that what I am asking for? Are you talking about certain edge cases which might break things?

Comment: I turned the remaining discussion into a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278206/lesscss-pass-parent-selector-to-a-method

Comment: Acually, it does work. I am not sure what was wrong earlier.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
.myColor{
    min-height:100%;
}


    .main{
        .nested{
            .morenested{
                .myColor;
            }
        }
    }
```

result:

```
/* Generated by less 2.4.0 */
.myColor {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.main .nested .morenested {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, like that. Only I don't want my rule to be defined under html.browser-ie. I can't have code living in separate places for each browser, impossible to maintain. There is another answer to this question below.